# Describing completed action

Tags: tenses, progressive-aspect, passive-voice, perfect-aspect

So, I was having a fight with an English grammar expert with my little knowledge on the following sentence :

> Products are already being checked.

My opponent was telling me that my sentence was wrong as it won't make any sense and also it doesn't describe a completed action. His answer was:

> Products have already been checked.

For my little or even less knowledge on grammar I was unable to find out if my answer was correct or not. That is why I'm forced to ask here.

Comment: The difference is nothing to do with grammar or "correctness". It's just a matter of the intended *meaning* (has the process of checking already *started*, or already *finished*?)

Comment: Not much of an expert.  I hope no one was hurt during the fight.

Comment: Your opponent is no expert: both sentences are perfectly valid. However, they do mean two different things. So if you said one but meant the other, then that would be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how he can claim that your sentence makes no sense and then give exactly the same sentence but in a different tense as a sentence that does make sense.

"Products are already being checked." Present Continuous

"Products have already been checked." Past

The use of the word [already](https://www.google.com/search?q=already)

> adverb
>   1. before or by now or the time in question.

(Google)

doesn't preclude the use of the present continuous tense. It just means the present continuous action began in the past, which of course they always do.

He is correct that the present continuous version does not describe a completed action. If that is the intention then his version is correct

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it make sense, describe completed action and be grammatically correct if I say "Products are already checked"?

Comment: @SaMax I think so but a lot less clearly: you're describing their current status of having been checked (in the past). If you need to say the products have been checked then why not just do that?

Comment: Cause, my opponent also said that I'd never be able to describe a completed action using "are".

Answer (score 0):

Your expert has a very flawed view. Your first example tells me that the process has started and is continuing right now. The second tells me that it started in the past and has now finished. Either is correct grammatically.

I also ask myself how "products are already being checked" differs from "products are being checked". I believe that the first has an extra sense that there has been an expectation that the products should be checked. For example - "Have you started that check yet?" "I'm already doing it".